# Pony Mail Gem Throws Broken Pipe Error

Tags: ruby, email, sinatra, pony

So I'm using sinatra, and I'm trying to send emails from the app for basic verification reasons. I was poking around the docs, and I found the gem pony, which seems to be right up my alley. In my app.rb file I have

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'pony'
require 'mail'

post '/signup' do
  Pony.mail  :to => "myself@me.com", :body => "User Sign Up!", :subject => "score"
end
```

but I end up with a broken pipe error. See below. 
I went in to the sendmail.rb, but any change to that and I just got different errors. I think some other people have experienced a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you send mail with Pony manually via IRB?

```
$ irb
>> require 'rubygems'
>> require 'pony'
>> mail = Pony.mail :to => "myself@me.com", :body => "User sign up!", :subject => "score"
```

You may need to add more options (such as SMTP servers).  See https://github.com/benprew/pony for configuration.

Comment: I couldn't initially, but using the command line, I was able to get the information I needed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself having the same problem as me, it's very easy to fix. Info [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54051/sendmail-error-on-os-x-mountain-lion)

Basically you just have to run these three lines in the terminal

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix set-permissions
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix start
```

This answer was given to me at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54051/sendmail-error-on-os-x-mountain-lion